# POSTing to webservice in .net 3.5 solution

Tags: asp.net, web-services, post, ektron

I'm at my wit's end here. I'm trying to use an auto-complete extender from the asp.net ajax extensions toolkit, which is filled from a bog-standard webservice. The application is a .net 3.5 web site, hosting the webservice in a subdirectory (real, not virtual).

Whenever I try to post to the webservice I get the following error: 
**The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/Workarea/webservices/FindAdvisorNameService.asmx/FindAdvisorName' is not allowed.**

To complicate matters, a co-worker of mine pulled down the solution and can run it fine.

After doing some Googling, it seems that there are some issues with URL rewriting, so I had him try using my web.config -- he still has no problem, and I still have no success.

Anyone have any thoughts on what could be up, or where to start looking?

To complicate matters, this is an `<a href="http://www.ektron.com">Ektron CMS400.Net</a>` solution, but he has the same version of Ektron installed that I do. The project was recently upgraded from the 2.0 to 3.5 framework, but still, it's in 3.5 on his machine as well.

I've checked the IIS mappings, and GET, POST, and DEBUG are allowed on ASMX files.

Help me Obi-Wan KeSObi, you're my only hope!

Edit: Oh, yeah, to complicate matters, this is a brand new machine I have, so there's not likely to be that much weird stuff in the registry, etc. etc.. The co-worker's machine is almost as new.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, found the issue with the help of a colleague. Seems the Ektron CMS added a mapping in IIS -- it mapped * to aspnet_isapi.dll. That overrode all the other mappings. I deleted that, and now things work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you rewriting URLs?  You need to exclude your web services from rewrites.